# Rspec/Capybara - Select Form should trigger Onchange event when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm new to TDD and I actually wrote the code before the tests. The code itself works fine and from the main page the onChange event applies. However, when testing, even though a different option is chosen as the selected option(so the option does change), it seems that the onchange event is not actualled trigger when testing and it stays on the same page.it says expected: "/ctscans/index", got: "/" (using ==)

welcome_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Welcome Page" do
    before {visit root_path}
    subject{page}
        describe "with Ctscan selected" do

            before {select("CT Scan", :from => "procedure")}

            it {should have_select('procedure', :selected => 'CT Scan')}
            it "redirects to" do    
                select 'MRI', :from => 'procedure'
                current_path.should == ctscans_index_path
            end
        end

end
```

views/welcome/index.html.erb

```
<%=select_tag(:procedure, options_for_select(@paths, :selected => @paths[0]),:onchange => "gotoNewPage()")%>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function gotoNewPage() {
        if (document.getElementById('procedure').value){
            window.location.href = document.getElementById('procedure').value;
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't indicated that the spec needs to use a javascript driver. Try

```
describe "with Ctscan selected", js: true do ...
```

Comment: hmm, ok I added that and I'm getting a Selenium::WebDriver:Error (Could not find Firefox binary (os=macosx). Make sure Firefox is installed on the machine. After searching for answers on this, it seems that most of theses have a features/support/env.rb and/or use cucumber. Would you know anything about this?

Comment: Assuming you do have Firefox installed, add `require 'capybara/rspec'` to your `spec_helper`. Cucumber shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I did that thanks. I just have to get Headless browsing working now. HAve you used PhantomJS + Ghost to do this

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with those.